# TP4056 modules with 18650 lithium cells

Tags: lithium

These tp4056 can charge at lithium battery up to 1A.
https://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Prototyping/TP4056.pdf

I would like to use them in series but charging each battery separetely because the TP4056 modules cannot be wired in serial due to common ground.

But i've made a schematic and i would like to know if it will work or explode.

Here :
[image]

In this circuit each module have a tp4056 chip, a dw01 single cell protection ic and a dual mosfet.

The switch is used for the charge or for out 11.1V so you won't be able to use the +11.1V while charging it and it's a dpst switch so no common ground problem.

Can I wire these modules in series?

Comment: Do you have a schematic diagram or detailed information for that PC board? I don't think we can make any real comment without more information on the board.

Comment: Schematic: [link](http://artofcircuits.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/TP4056_Protected_Battery_Charger-3.jpg)
TP4056 datasheet: [link](https://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Prototyping/TP4056.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

According to the board schematic, the input and output ground terminals are connected together.

Therefore, in your drawing, the "Gnd charge" wire will short-circuit the outputs of the bottom two boards, so your circuit won't work.

You would need charge control boards with galvanic isolation between the input and output sides to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, i thought about that but someone did it and it work :
[here a youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQuGJQD4KrY)

Comment: that build does not allow charging.