# TP4056 to charge xS1P li-po li-ion

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, lipo

Very related to this [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/274020/tp4056-modules-with-18650-lithium-cells).

While it's already clear that several TP4056 can't be used to charge and discharge several cells, it's not clear to me if it's possible to only charge a battery pack with several cells in series.

The input and output GND pads are connected, but what about the battery terminals? From the TP chip datasheet I fear that B- pad is also connected to GND, and therefore i can't charge a battery pack from it's balance connector, but i'm not that good in diagram reading and understanding and i hope to be proven wrong (maybe thanks to the additional protection chip, dw01 if i'm not wrong).

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie: you're right! Replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*it's not clear to me if it's possible to only charge a battery pack with several cells in series.*

It is clearly answered in the [datasheet](https://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Prototyping/TP4056.pdf):

DESCRIPTION
The TP4056 is a complete constant-current/constant-voltage linear charger **for single cell lithium-ion batteries**.

At the end of page 3 there's a schematic which will be very similar to what is on most TP4056 modules:

[image]

Note how the - terminal of the battery is also grounded. On the module you can also easily see (and measure) that IN- / GND and B- are shorted. So indeed, the TP4056 is **not suited** for balanced charging of series connected cells.

If you need to charge series connected cells then you need a **different IC**.

Comment: any recommendation for that different IC?